# Kendo DataSource appends Schema Id on datasoure sync

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

Just want to know why push method of the javascript inserts "index"

```
   var agendaBatch=[];

    for(var i=0; i<agendas.length; i++) {

        var agenda = {
            MeetingId: meetingId,
            Title: agendas[i].title,
            Description: agendas[i].description,
            Remarks: "",
        };

        agendaBatch.push(agenda);   
    }

    console.log(kendo.stringify(agendaBatch));
    dataSourceAgenda.add(agendaBatch);

    dataSourceAgenda.sync();
```

output:

```
{"0":{"Title":"Agenda title","Description":"Agenda details","Remarks":""},
 "1":{"Title":"Agenda title","Description":"Agenda details","Remarks":""}}
```

what I expect is this output to match my Web API parameter requirement

```
[{"Title":"Agenda title","Description":"Agenda details","Remarks":""},
 {"Title":"Agenda title","Description":"Agenda details","Remarks":""}]
```

Any suggestions how can I do this?....

UPDATE: just found out a moment ago, I'm using kendo ui datasource, I fixed the problem when I removed the Id on the schema

```
var dataSourceAgenda = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                type: "odata",
                create: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: API_URL + "/agendas",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json'
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options) {
                        return kendo.stringify(options);
                    } 
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id", //I get my desired output if this is removed
                    fields: {
                        MeetingId: { type: "number" },
                        Title: { type: "string" },
                        Description: { type: "string" },
                        Remarks: { type: "string" },
                    }
                },
            }        
        });
```

HOWEVER I need to the Id parameter in other functions, is there anyway I can do this without removing the Id in kendo datasource.

Changed the Question title!

Comment: looks more like a problem with `kendo.stringify` not serializing the array properly. what is the result with `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the documentation of Kendo UI DataSource ([here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-add)), `add` method accepts an `Object` not an `array` of `Object`.

In addition, you use as `id` a field called `Id` that is not among the fields of your `model`.

Try doing the following:

```
var dataSourceAgenda = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        create      : function (op) {
            ...
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options) {
                return kendo.stringify(options.models);
            }
        }
    },
    batch    : true,
    schema   : {
        model: {
            id    : "Id", //I get my desired output if this is removed
            fields: {
                Id         : { type: "number" },
                MeetingId  : { type: "number" },
                Title      : { type: "string" },
                Description: { type: "string" },
                Remarks    : { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I.e.:

1. Set `batch` to `true` for being able to send multiple requests at a time when you invoke `sync`.
2. Define `Id` in the `schema.model.fields` definition.
3. Do the `stringify` of `options.models`.

Answer (score 0):

As `agendaBatch` is obviously an array, I assume that `kendo.stringify` is not serializing it properly. You could go with `JSON.stringify`.

Note that this is not implemented by older browsers. If you need to support them, you could include the script by Douglas Crockford:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

---

**EDIT**

Now that you changed your question - I am not really familiar with kendo ui, so **this really is just a wild guess** in an attempt to help you with your updated problem.

It looks like you have access to the `data` in the `beforeSend` function. You could try to manipulate it for your needs, like this maybe:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr, s) {
    var arrayData = [];

    for (var id in s.data) {
        arrayData.push(s.data[id]);
    }

    s.data = arrayData;
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit, its not actuallly the kendo.stringify. Its the actual value that was passed in fiddler.

Comment: now i am not familiar with kendo ui, but i made an edit that might at least help you find a solution...

Comment: not working.. I guess I have to manually remove the index in the json string

Comment: when I stringify the s.data this is what i get ["{","\"","0","\"",":","{","\"","T","i","t","l","e","\"",":","\"","A","g","e","n","d","a"," ","t","i","t","l","e","\"",",","\"","D","e","s","c","r","i","p","t","i","o","n","\"",":","\"","A","g","e","n","d","a"," ","d","e","t","a","i","l","s","\"",",","\"","R","e","m","a","r","k","s","\"",":","\"","\"","}",",","\"","1","\"",":","{","\"","T","i","t","l","e","\"",":","\"","A","g","e","n","d","a"," ","t","i","t","l","e","\"",",","\"","D","e","s","c"...

Comment: I dont how it's gets messed up

Comment: is that what you get for `stringify` after you assigned it with `s.data = arrayData;`? in that case, `s.data` is probably already a string and my solution is not correct for that case.